# ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: operator (*)

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I am trying hard to find out solution for this unexpected error its working fine when i run dev but its giving me error when i push to Heroku Please help me to solve this issue.

My Webpack Configeration

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            js: 'babel-loader'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      hash: false,
      template: './pages/template.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        drop_console: false,
      }
    })
  ],
```

My package.js setting

```
{
  "name": "vue-fullpage.js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "buzzelement Website App",
  "main": "./src/FullPage.vue",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.config.dev.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "main": "webpack --config=webpack.config.js pages/main/src/index.js pages/main/dist/build.js",
    "stand-alone": "concurrently 'webpack --config=webpack.config.build.js src/FullPage.vue pages/stand-alone/build.min.js --output-library=fullPage'  'webpack --config=webpack.config.build.js src/fullPageMixin.js pages/stand-alone/mixin.min.js --output-library=fullPageMixin'",
    "build": "webpack --config=webpack.config.build.js src/FullPage.vue dist/build.min.js --output-library=fullPage",
    "mixin": "webpack --config=webpack.config.build.js src/fullPageMixin.js dist/mixin.min.js --output-library=fullPageMixin",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run main"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "msaqib83@bitbucket.org/buzzelement/buzzelement-com.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "foobar": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": ">=1.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.2",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.6.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.7.0",
    "npm": "5.8.0",
    "yarn": "1.2.0"
  }
}
```

It would be great if some one help me out for this issue i tried alot over here but couldnt find proper answer